# Proving a function is bounded near its limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

> If $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a }g(x) = M$$ show there exists a numer $\delta>0$ such that 
>   $$ 0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |g(x)|<1+|M| $$

**Attempt**
$$ 0<|x-a|<\delta \implies \epsilon>|g(x)-M|\geq |g(x)|-|M|$$
If $\epsilon =1$ then 
$$1+|M|>|g(x)|$$

Is this correct?

Moreover is it possible to do it backward (starting from $|g(x)|<1+|M| $ and showing $ |g(x)-M|<\epsilon)$?

Comment: The forward direction is perfectly correct (though it would be best to _start_ with $\epsilon = 1$, and to use existence of the limit to _choose_ $\delta > 0$ such that...). The backward direction is not true: $|0| < 1 + |M|$ for all real $M$, but $|0 - M| < 1$ is generally false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof could include some more set-up, such as: "because $\lim_\limits{x\to a}g(x)=M$ we have $\forall\varepsilon>0\exists\delta:|x-a|<\delta\implies |g(x)-M|<\varepsilon$", but these additional things really depend on the audience that the proof is intended for. The main idea of the proof is accurate, where you use $|x-y|\geq||x|-|y||\geq |x|-|y|$.

To address your second question: we cannot go in the reverse direction unless we assume that $\lim_\limits{x\to a}g(x)=M$, in which case the result is very obvious (by the limit definition). Take for instance $g(x)=1$ on $\Bbb R$, and then $M=2$. Then clearly $|g(x)|\leq |M|+1$ however $|g(x)-M|\not <\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: Oh okay perfect. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

And answer to the first question is “yes”. It is perfect.

As to the other question, the answer is negative, of course. Since the statement “$|g(x)|<1+|M|$” does not involve $\epsilon$, you cannot deduce something about $\epsilon$ from it.